# how to use the azures module of poweshell on a mac

Tags: azure-powershell

i need to access some cmdlets from the AzureAD module in PowerShell 7 or 7.1 on a Mac Big Sur.

1. Installed Powershell with home-brew
2. used the docker image for powershell from Microsoft

When i import the Module AzureAD i get the following error

```
Import-Module AzureAD Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

After some research it seems that MacOS is not currently not supported for both cases above.

How are other doing this ?

thx, Joe

UPDATE:
apparently the following works.

```
   >Register-PackageSource -Trusted -ProviderName 'PowerShellGet' -Name 'Posh Test Gallery' -Location https://www.poshtestgallery.com/api/v2/ 
    Register-PackageSource: Package Source 'Posh Test Gallery' exists.
    
    >Install-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview
    >Import-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview
    WARNING: /Users/joe/.local/share/powershell/Modules/AzureAD.Standard.Preview/0.1.599.7
    WARNING: AzureAD.Standard.Preview
    WARNING: /Users/joe/.local/share/powershell/Modules/AzureAD.Standard.Preview/0.1.599.7/net471
    WARNING: Loading module in coreclr folder: 'netstandard2.0' ...
>Connect-AzureAD
WARNING: To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code sx22443 to authenticate.
```

here

Comment: `AzureAD` has .NET dependencies, which won't work on Linux/OSX by default. The `Az` module does have `*AzAD*` cmdlets you can use however. Really depends on what you want to do with AAD.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but partial support

```
 >Register-PackageSource -Trusted -ProviderName 'PowerShellGet' -Name 'Posh Test Gallery' -Location https://www.poshtestgallery.com/api/v2/ 
    Register-PackageSource: Package Source 'Posh Test Gallery' exists.
    
    >Install-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview
    >Import-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview
    WARNING: /Users/joe/.local/share/powershell/Modules/AzureAD.Standard.Preview/0.1.599.7
    WARNING: AzureAD.Standard.Preview
    WARNING: /Users/joe/.local/share/powershell/Modules/AzureAD.Standard.Preview/0.1.599.7/net471
    WARNING: Loading module in coreclr folder: 'netstandard2.0' ...
>Connect-AzureAD
WARNING: To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code sx22443 to authenticate.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as of the time of my comment, the Posh Test Gallery is down.