# How can I assign an exiting user as owner to a newly created ADgroup in Azure Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I've searched the documentation and can't see how to add an existing user as an owner to an AD group.

`Add-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $GroupObjectId -RefObjectId $UserObjectId` is not recognized as a command. The version of Powershell I'm using is seen in the image attached. Is it worth not using Azure Powershell and using Graph API instead?

See second image for an example of the error message:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you install the azure ad module ?

Comment: I believe so, by running Install-Module -Name "AzureAD"

Comment: try import-module AzureAD before running you script ?

Comment: I have tried that and seeing Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral...The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Are you running the script from the same user you have install the module ?

Comment: yes I am doing that

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and  able to add the owner to newly created group successfully.

[image]

- This is the newly created group .

[image]

I have added the existing user from AD.
[image]

The error might be  to azure AD module  install or connection issue .Import the module if azure module is already installed  or install azure module if not already installed, before actual commands and connect to Azure AD.

These are the commands used.

```js
Install-Module AzureAD
Import-Module AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD
$UserObjectId="***************"
$GroupObjectId="**************"
Add-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $GroupObjectId -RefObjectId $UserObjectId
```

and try  command  from the administrative account .

Comment: Are you on a Mac? I think the issue is because I'm on a Mac

Comment: I am on windows.To set up powershell for macOS,you may need to install Homebrew , powershell v7 and other modules and then connect to az account to use commands as usual. See [reference 1](https://techgenix.com/powershell-in-macos/)  and  [SOreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65438658/how-to-use-the-azures-module-of-poweshell-on-a-mac)